# How to store the image path in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-core

This is the code of my backend controller (asp.net core 3.1)
[image]

my front end code (angularJS)

[image]

[image]

my team has decided that we will upload the path of the these images stored in this folder in database, and later we will be uploading images in a different way. The main thing that we are stuck on is how to actually store these images path in database?

[image]

this is the code for my uploadimage button. We just need to store the path of the images in database, can someone help me here?

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Post code as text instead.

Answer (score 1):

You've done the hard bit already as you have the variable **filepath** already set.

Do you have a database already set up to post to? If so it will just be a case of calling your **dbcontext.Add(filepath)** to add to the database. Otherwise you'll need to get setup which is out of scope of the question.

I would create a model with some sort of identifier, and then the filepath to make it easier to track down later.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use EFcore to add data to database,here is a simple demo:

Your Controller:

```
private readonly YourContext _context;
public void YourController(YourContext context)
{
    _context=context;
}
[HttpPost(nameof(UploadFiles))]
public async Task<ActionReuslt> UploadFiles(IFormFile file)
{
    ...
    _context.Files.Add(new FileModel{FileName=file.FileName,FilePath=filePath});
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

model:

```
public class FileModel
{
    public int FileId{get;set;}
    public string FileName{get;set;}
    public string FilePath{get;set;}
}
```

YourContext:

```
public class YourContext: DbContext
    {
        public YourContext(DbContextOptions<YourContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<FileModel> Files{ get; set; }
    }
```

Configuration:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<YourContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "..."
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

For more details,you can refer to the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0).